# Use another symfony2 project as vendor

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, vendor

I have three projects X, Y and Z.

Project X does some admin functions for Y poject. The Entities for project Y are writen in the AppBudnle vendor. Now, I would like to also do some admin tasks for the project Z in X, but project Z has all entities in the src/Company/Z/Entity/...

I included the project Z as vendor in the project X with this autoload:

```
"autoload": {
            "psr-0": {
                "Company\\Z\\": ""
            }
        },
```

But when adding this to the AppKernel in the project X, it complains that

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Company\ZBundle\ZBundle' not found in ....
```

Am I missing something in the autoload?

The project Z entities dir is seen like this in the X project:

```
/vendor/company/z-bundle/company/ZBundle/src/company/ZBundle/Entity
```

Comment: DId you try with "repositories" in composer.json ? Could you show us how you call it in AppKernel please ?

Comment: Hi Delphine, in the composer.json, I only added `company/z" : "dev-master`. In AppKernel, There is: `new Company\ZBundle\ZBundle()`

Comment: File systems tend to be case sensitive.  src/company vs Company.  Composer 'compiles' the various autoload paths for performance.  Sometimes it's helpful to look in vendor/composer to see what is going on.  And don't forget to run composer dumpautoload after making changes to composer.json so your autoload changes gets picked up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create an answer because comment section is too short :

In your composer.json try something like this, according to your own project :

```
     "repositories": [
            {
                "type": "vcs",
                "url": "git@github.com:You/companyZBundle.git"
            },
     ], 
     "require": {
           "php": ">=5.3.9",
         ...
        "You/companyZBundle": "dev-master@dev"
      }
```

In your AppKernel :

```
new Company\ZBundle\ZBundle()
```

And, as Cerad said, be careful about case !